# Lint discrepancies between different machines

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, lint

I have a multi module android app which has lint configured to run prior to pushing to github, as a pre-push hook. I have 2 different machines (both Mac) which I use to write code for this app.

On one machine lint flags an error due to Missing Permissions. The permission that lint is looking for is declared in a different module and the app compiles, builds and runs as expected, so this being done correctly is not in question. I'm also part of a team of 5 and no one else sees this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<issues format="5" by="lint 3.6.2">

<issue
    id="MissingPermission"
    severity="Error"
    message="Missing permissions required by TelephonyManager.getNetworkType: android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
    category="Correctness"
    priority="9"
    summary="Missing Permissions"
    explanation="This check scans through your code and libraries and looks at the APIs being used, and checks this against the set of permissions required to access those APIs. If the code using those APIs is called at runtime, then the program will crash.&#xA;&#xA;Furthermore, for permissions that are revocable (with targetSdkVersion 23), client code must also be prepared to handle the calls throwing an exception if the user rejects the request for permission at runtime."
    errorLine1="    return when (telephonyManager.networkType) {"
    errorLine2="                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~">
    <location
        file="/Users/chris/myproject/dependencies/network/CellularInfoImpl.kt"
        line="47"
        column="18"/>
</issue>
```

I've checked the following list to ensure that both machines are running the same configuration.

- Android Studio version.
- It's the same code base on the same branch.
- Gradle plugin version
- gradle.properties
- gradle-wrapper.properties
- Android Studios preferences for Correctness Inspections. (Missing permissions is ticked on both)
- lint config.xml
- lint version, taken from the lint report after completing the gradle task.

My question is, what else could be causing the discrepancy? Where else should I be looking to attempt to resolve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to add a SuppressWarning annotation for Missing Permissions. This overcomes the problem by stopping the lint warnings, but doesn't actually solve it.